# Typescript Jest react testing library configuration

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I'm getting an error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module` while trying to run a jest react library test. Jest and React Testing library are simply trying to import React and other modules to be used for testing.

[image]

[image]

I believe error is in the jest config, trying transforming the typescript into jsx (I assume) in order to run the tests. From what I've read its the transform and transformIgnorePatterns that need to work together.

my jest.config file is as follows

```
module.exports = {
roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],

// Jest transformations -- this adds support for TypeScript
// using ts-jest
transform: {
    "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    // "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest" /// commented code 
},

preset: 'ts-jest',

testEnvironment: 'node',

transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/react"],

setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
],

moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": " 
<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
},

// Test spec file resolution pattern
// Matches parent folder `__tests__` and filename
// should contain `test` or `spec`.
testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",

moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
```

};

I have tried to configure bable to transform the tsx and jsx also but with noluck:
my babel.config.js file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
     ],
};
```

I've based everything off the jest config docs and all the other stack overflow and git answer I could find but still no luck. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: do you have allow JS in your tsconfig?

Comment: Is your test file a .tsx file ?